# Анимация пропорционального уменьшение блока до display:none с расположением к центру

Tags: javascript, css, css3, анимация

Подскажите, есть ли возможность реализовать анимацию при которой div "схлопывался" не в верхний левый угол, а к центру своего размещения. Приведу пример:

```js
$(".button").on("click", function() {
  $(".block").toggleClass("active");
   setTimeout(function () {
       $(".block").toggleClass("hidden");
   }, 300)
});
```

```css
.button {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background: red;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.block {
  width: 200px;
  height: 240px;
  transition: .2s ease-in;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
.hidden{
display:none;
}

.active{
transform: scale(0);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class='button'></button>
<div class="block"></div>
```

Можно ли как-то сменить точку отсчета ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Может быть Вам подойдет `transform:scale(0)`

```js
$(".button").on("click", function() {
  $(".block").toggleClass('scale0');
});
```

```css
.button {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background: red;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.block {
  width: 200px;
  height: 240px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  transition: 300ms
}

.scale0{
  transform:scale(0)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class='button'></button>
<div class="block"></div>
```

Comment: С этим видом анимации проблемка, поскольку при transform объект не убирается из потока. В моем случаи данный эффект будет примнется к группе div-ов и при уменьшении transform:scale(0) они занимают всё столько же рабочего места хотя и становятся невидимыми. Если же к классу добавлять display:none; То он срабатывает раньше чем анимация. Ну, а повесить переход из display:block в display:none; через анимации не получается поскольку свойство не поддается анимации

Comment: есть слушатель на transitionend...

Comment: можно подробнее, как его использовать ?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/Events/transitionend

Comment: Спасибо. Да, это помогло. Было б ещё интересно, если бы можно было сделать обратный эффект, тоже с плавностью анимации

Comment: @BlackStar1991 нужно сначала навесить видимость, и в сеттаймауте уже класс анимации

Comment: Да, я где-то так и сделал... вот только с обратной анимацией на второй клик всё идет не так гладко (*поменял начальный код)